# How do I compile Python C extensions using MinGW inside a virtualenv?

Tags: python, mingw, virtualenv

When using virtualenv in combination with the MinGW compiler on Windows, compiling a C extension results in the following error:

```
C:\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -lpython25 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status 
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

What should one do to successfully compile C extensions?

Answer (score 6):

Set the `LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable so MinGW knows where to find the system-wide Python `libpython25.a`.

Place a line in your virtualenv's `activate.bat`:

```
set LIBRARY_PATH=c:\python25\libs
```

Or set a global environment variable in Windows.

Be sure to change `25` to correspond to your version of Python if you're not using version 2.5.

Comment: Thanks so much for updating your question with the answer. Was struggling with this same problem and this was the problem!